How do i fix this knee?
I wanted to pose this model but as you can see the knees don't work properly even with auto rig pro the knees do the same how can I fix that?


heres the model link : https://mega.nz/file/7DwlmCDS#mwhVEf1yR4nKKAlO9sgcxjvZ4wqLIqJfF7IX3-9l-_Y

Hi. Please don't post essential information like links, file downloads or additional details in the comments section where it can be easily missed. Instead edit them into your original post with the [Edit] button above. Comments are transitory by nature, are hard to index or search for, and may be erased at any moment.

You could redo the parentage With Automatic Weights. Also, unless you have a good reason not to, put Subdivision Surface at the bottom of the modifiers stack.
Put your armature in Rest Pose, only display Layer 30, move the leg bones a bit backwards:

Remove the legs vertices from all vertex groups:

Select the armature, shift select the mesh, swith to Weight Paint mode, select all the legs bones with ShiftAlt and Weights > Assign Automatic from Bones:


thank you ! that didnt completely fix it but its a big improvement
